# Mule Junit Testing a <ws:proxy/> pattern

Tags: mule, junit4, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have a mule xml that doesn't have a flow but using  pattern to achieve the result.

How to unit test this pattern as flow is not present?

My xml looks like:

```
<mule>
 <ws:proxy>
 </ws:proxy
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually test my mule flows using a "black box" approach, and I do not execute my flows directly. Instead, I generate a web request directly using perhaps the Jersey HTTP client.

In your case, you probably want to make sure that the proxied web service is not called during your test. You can mock the service using the [confluex-mock-http](https://github.com/Confluex/confluex-mock-http) library or something similar.

Comment: Will try and let u know

Comment: Just a heads up, we've moved the confluex-mock-http project to http://github.com/shamsoftware/sham-http since the time this question was answered.